# comparing list element (string) to a character, but getting error message in regard to an integer

Tags: python

Why does this line of code;

```
if (inputlist[x]) is ("r"):
```

Give me this error message;

```
if (inputlist[x]) is ("r"):
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

All list elements are single characters, type of string. I cannot imagine where the `integer` part of the error comes from?!?!

Comment: Can you post complete code?? What is X???? also post inputlist

Comment: Wild guess: if you're doing `for x in inputlist:`, then you can't use `x` to index `inputlist`. Try `if x == "r":` instead.

Comment: the error is obvious. x as an index is supposed to be an integer. So what is x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, your `inputlist` variable is pointing to a string object and to access individual characters you need to use `integer` as an index.

```
inputlist[2] = # Something
```

You might be doing something like this:

```
inputlist = "hello world"
for x in inputlist:
    if (inputlist[x]) is ("r"):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Output:

```
if (inputlist[x]) is ("r"):
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, you need to do something like this:

```
inputlist = "hello world"
for x in inputlist:
    if x == "r":
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Thank you abhiarora, you were absolutely correct, I very much appreciate it !

Comment: Great. Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, x is most likely what's causing your problem. In order to use string[x], x represents the index position, so x must be an integer. If x is not an integer, you will get the TypeError.